# Convert from cvpoint to cvpoint2d32f

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

How do I convert from cvpoint to cvpoint2d32f?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CvPoint p = cvPoint(x,y);
CvPoint2D32f p2 = cvPoint2D32f(p.x,p.y);
```