# How to retrieve the contour points - convert in to vector using opencv ?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, vector, contour

How to retrieve the contour points  - opencv ?

My Image has three Objects ( irregular shape )
i have found the contour of above three objects.

**My declaration - Contours **

`vector<vector<Point>> contours;`

So i got the object co-ordinates like below

```
contours.[size] = 3
         [capacity ] = 14
         +[0] {size = 330 }
         +[1] {size = 240 }
         +[2] {size = 654 }
```

here i have three contours, with size of 330, 240,654

Now my Doubt is how to Copy the each contour points of 3 objects to vector ?

I want to use this contour points in `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` function as `prevPts`

Or what can be done ?

Comment: Just use `contours[0]`, `contours[1]` and `contours[2]` for them.

Comment: @herohuyongtao How should i just copy from contours to `vector<vector<Point>> contours` to `CvPoint2D32f MyVector`.

Comment: `CvPoint2D32f` is just one point, if you need to copy one to it, check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16772174/2589776).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>- A little bit more explanation of my above comment.</sub>

[**`calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk) can directly use `vector<Point>` or `vector<Point2f>` for parameter `prevPts`.

> **`prevPts`** – vector of 2D points for which the flow needs to be found; point coordinates must be single-precision floating-point numbers.

That said, you only need to use `contours[0]`, `contours[1]` and `contours[2]` for the 3 objects (they are of type `vector<Point>`) and pass them to `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`.

Answer (score 0):

herohuyongtao gave you the correct answer. You should give him recognition by selecting his answer as the correct answer.

I'll just add a small explanation : your contours is a vector of vector. It has 3 elements, and each of these elements is a vector of points (accessible by using .x and.y). That is exactly what is required by prevPts. 
By sending contour[i] to the function you are sending the i-th vector of points. 
See here  :http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html